# Nondegenerate critical point

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, derivatives

I don't understand this part from the book of Zeidler , can someone help me to understand it ?

[image]

Please

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If $u_0$ is a non degenerate critical point for some function $f$ then under a smooth change of coordinates, $u_0$ is still a non degenerate critical point.

Comment: but mhy they say: since $\varphi'(u_0)\neq 0$ , this fact follows easily from the chain rule ,please thank you

Comment: The chain rule says $(f\circ \phi)'(u_0) = f'(\phi(u_0))\phi'(u_0) = f'(u_0) \phi'(u_0)$. Now ask yourself what it means to be a critical point of $f$ in different coordinates.

Comment: $u_0$ is a critical point of f if $f'(u_0)=0$, so if it is a critical point to $f$ it still a critical point of $f\circ\varphi$, to see that it is nondegenerate : $(f\circ\varphi)''(u_0)=f''(u_0)\varphi'(u_0)+f'(u_0)\varphi''(u_0)\neq 0$ since $\varphi'(u_o)\neq0$. right ?

Comment: one question please: why $\varphi'(u_0)\neq 0$ ?